# How to write a script for bash to archive a directory and keep its name?

Tags: linux, bash

For my uni I need to write a simple script that makes backups of few directories and move them to another directories. I'm very new to Linux so I'm kinda lost. Before that, they showed how to archive with tar and compress with gzip, so I'm assuming that's how I need to do those backups. It is also beginner level, so the script should be as simple as possible.
Here's my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo

directories="work/ extract/ test/"

for directory in $directories

do

tar --create --gzip --file= ~/backups  "$directory".tgz $directory

done
```

And that's the outcome:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ./my_backup.sh

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: : Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: : Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: : Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I can only guess it's something to do with the names, because '/' is not allowed in names, I think, but I don't know how to remove it. I asked this question on my uni's forum, but nobody answered.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `directories="work/ extract/ test/"` is a string, you want an array to loop through with for, which would be `directories=("work/" "extract/" "test/")`

Comment: Your tar line is bogus.

Comment: No luck here either:
`pi@raspberry:~ $ ./my_backup.sh

tar: Removing leading /' from member names
tar: work.tgz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: : Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

directories=(work extract test)

for directory in ${directories[@]}; do
    tar -czf "${HOME}/backups/${directory}.tgz" "${directory}"
done
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks. Could you tell me what `set -e` means? And also `[@]` in `${directories[@]}`? I don't think I'm gonna do many more scripts, but it's good to understand why it works.

Comment: `set -e` means to exit when a command doesn't return 0 (true), `${directories[@]}` is syntax for array in BASH.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just put the directories into a list do iterate through them via a for loop.
So instead of

`directories="work/ extract/ test/"`

write

`directories=("work" "extract" "test")`

if you use the script in the same directory as the directories you need to backup are.

I wasnt able to test it yet, but I think it should work this way.

Comment: No luck:
`pi@raspberry:~ $ ./my_backup.sh

tar: Removing leading /' from member names
tar: work.tgz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar (child): : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: : Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`